# How to convert a JPG image to TGA with PHP (preferably in CodeIgniter)?

Tags: php, codeigniter, jpeg, image-conversion, tga

We're developing a website and for a particular section user is uploading images. User can upload a jpg file, which on upload we need to convert it to TGA format.

Is there any PHP or CI library which can do this? I know this is not possible with GD library or PHP image magic.

Thanks for any help.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that with PHP imagemagick's [setImageFormat](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagick-setimageformat.php)!

And imagemagick [support TGA](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/formats.php) (Read, Write).

From the comments:

```
<?php
        $image = new Imagick();

        $image->setResolution(300, 300);
        $image->readImageBlob(...);
        // convert the output to TGA
        $image->setImageFormat('tga');
?>
```